# Timer initialization and Race condition in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, timer

I saw this code on Richter's book :

> The following code demonstrates how to have a thread pool thread call
> a method starting immediately and then every 2 seconds thereafter:

```
/*1*/    internal static class TimerDemo
/*2*/    {
/*3*/        private static Timer s_timer;
/*4*/        public static void Main()
/*5*/        {
/*6*/            Console.WriteLine("Checking status every 2 seconds");
/*7*/            // Create the Timer ensuring that it never fires. This ensures that
/*8*/            // s_timer refers to it BEFORE Status is invoked by a thread pool thread
/*9*/            s_timer = new Timer(Status, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
/*10*/            // Now that s_timer is assigned to, we can let the timer fire knowing
/*11*/            // that calling Change in Status will not throw a NullReferenceException
/*12*/            s_timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
/*13*/            Console.ReadLine(); // Prevent the process from terminating
/*14*/        }
/*15*/        // This method's signature must match the TimerCallback delegate
/*16*/        private static void Status(Object state)
/*17*/        {
/*18*/            // This method is executed by a thread pool thread
/*20*/            Console.WriteLine("In Status at {0}", DateTime.Now);
/*21*/            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulates other work (1 second)
/*22*/            // Just before returning, have the Timer fire again in 2 seconds
/*23*/            s_timer.Change(2000, Timeout.Infinite);
/*24*/            // When this method returns, the thread goes back
/*25*/            // to the pool and waits for another work item
/*26*/        }
/*27*/    }
```

However , (sorry) , I still don't understand what lines `#7,#8` means

And of course - why was it initialized (line #9) to `Timeout.Infinite` ( which is obviously : "*don't start the timer*")

*( I do understand the general purpose for preventing overlaps  , but I believe there is also a <strike>GC</strike> race condition pov here.)*

## edit

the namespace is `System.Threading`

Comment: It's to prevent a race between the callback `Status` being executed for the first time and the assignment to `s_timer`, it's not related to GC.

Comment: And it's really clever, I would never have though to such tricks. Kudos to *Jeffrey Richter*!

Comment: In this particular case the Sleep(1000) will also prevent the race condition. Makes the example a little contrived.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Why would it prevent the race? If the main thread is never awakened the code will crash too. Am I missing something?...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's not related to the GC but rather to avoid a **race condition**:

**The assignment operation is not atomic: first you create the Timer object then you assign it.**

So here is a scenario:

- `new Timer(...)` creates the timer and it starts "counting"
- the current thread is **preempted BEFORE the assignment ends** => `s_timer` is still null
- the **timer wakes up on another thread** and calls `Status` but the initial thread has **not yet finished the assignment operation**!
- `Status` accesses `s_timer` which is a **null reference** => **BOOM!**

With his method it can't happen, e.g. with the same scenario:

- the timer is created but does not start
- the current thread is preempted
- **nothing happens** because the timer has not yet started to raise events
- the initial thread is running again
- it **ends the assignment** => `s_timer` **references the timer**
- the timer is started safely: any future call to `Status` is valid because `s_timer` is a valid reference

Comment: Did they use the timer this way instead of just declaring the timer like that: new Timer(Status, null, 0, 2000) to prevent the Status method from being invoked while it's still running?

Comment: how the "the timer wakes up on another thread" if its assignment ( static) is NOT  complete ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The invocation of Timer's constructor will cause the timer to start running (when passing non infinite time spans), the variable assignment just holds another reference to the Timer object and won't affect its behavior.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: **new** creates the object in memory before it is referenced by `s_timer`. There is two operations there.

Comment: @Pragmateek So are you talking about code like this ? ---> `new Timer(...).start()`

Comment: We don't see the using by I guess this is a **System.Threading.Timer** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Threading.Timer.aspx). So it'll start once created.

Comment: @RoyiNamir If you want a timer with similar features but a richer interface you can use **System.Timers.Timer** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) Moreover if I remember well **System.Threading.Timer** is **not thread-safe** but **System.Timers.Timer** is (to be confirmed)...

Comment: @Pragmateek Im still struggeling with your assumption. I dont have here any 2 threads. (also richter doesnt mention it). all i have is  main static mthod and a static timer. I cant digest your answer to an non-existing code of myne.

Comment: @Pragmateek ignore my last comment. (my mind is off right now.) :-) timer starts at a threadpool thread ( another threadpool thread)

Comment: Here is a really good [MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) comparing the 3 types of timers to find out more info about the difference between `System.Timers.Timer`, `System.Threading.Timer`, and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: @Pragmateek still  , stupid question though , but why would `status` should ever want to touch `s_timer` ( leave my sample code which already solves this) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Often you don't want an operation to repeat forever, only when you detect a certain state; so you check a condition at each new tick and decide whether or not to reschedule the operation using the timer. As an example you could implement some polling this way adding one more second each time, or you may want to simply stop the timer once you're done. In any case you need to access it from your tick handler.

Answer (score 3):

It is a race, but there's more to it than meets the eye.  The obvious failure mode is when the main thread loses the processor and doesn't run for a while, more than a second.  And thus never gets around to updating the s_timer variable, kaboom in the callback.

A much more subtle issue is present on machines with multiple processor cores.  In that the updated variable value actually needs to be *visible* on the cpu core that runs the callback code.  Which reads memory through a cache, that cache is liable to contain stale content and still have the s_time variable at null when it is read.  That normally requires a *memory barrier*.  A low-level version of it is available from the Thread.MemoryBarrier() method.  There is no code whatsoever in the posted version that ensures that this happens.

It works in practice because the memory barrier is *implicit*.  The operating system cannot get a threadpool thread started, required here to get the callback going, without itself taking a memory barrier.  The side effect of which now also also ensures that the callback thread uses the update value of the s_time variable.  Relying on this side-effect doesn't win any prizes, but works in practice.  But also won't work if Richter's workaround isn't used since the barrier may well be taken before the assignment.  And thus the likelier failure mode on processors with a weak memory model, like Itanium and ARM.

Comment: There is no “more than a second”, the `Timer` is supposed to tick for the first time immediately.

Comment: No, the race is on s_timer, the Sleep delays accessing that variable.