# Inserting line numbers using Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

suppose a user paste this code in text box :

```
public static void Main()
         {
             int a=1+1;
             int b=1+1;
         }
```

I want to find in regex all the begining of lines and to add sequentials numbers as : (desired  output:)

```
/*0*/public static void Main()
/*1*/         {
/*2*/             int a=1+1;
/*3*/             int b=1+1;
/*4*/         }
```

[**JSBIN : I did managed to do something with :**](http://jsbin.com/uboroz/4/edit)

```
 newVal = oldVal.replace(/^(\b)(.*)/img, function (match, p1, p2, offset, string)
    {
        return '~NUM~' + p2;
    });
```

But ( 2 problems ) :

it seems that the first group in `/^(\b)(.*)/` is not the beginning of the line  ,

also it doesnt do it for all rows - although i did specify the `m` flag.

what am I doing wrong ?

*(for now , please leave the sequential numbers ...I will deal with it later. a const string is enough.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
var str ='public static void Main()\n{\n    int a=1+1;\n    int b=1+1;\n}',
i=0;
str = str.replace(/^/gm, function (){return '/*'+(++i)+'*/';});

console.log(str);
```

EDIT: (tribute to Rob W)

A word boundary `\b` is a zero-width cesure between a character which belongs to the `\w` class and another character from `\W` class or an anchor (`^` `$`).

Thus `^\b.` will match only when the dot stands for [0-9a-zA-Z_] (or \w).

Notice: A word boundary between to characters, can be replaced with:

`.\b.     <=>     (?=\w\W|\W\w)..`

Comment: Now I will be able to ask question with code with line references. ( here at SO - like i did here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263326/timer-initialization-and-race-condition-in-c)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: sorry, i have forgotten to number my lines!

Answer (score 2):

The word boundary does not match because `<start of line><whitespace>` is not a word boundary.

I would use:

```
var count = 0;
newVal = oldVal.replace(/^/mg, function() {
    return '/*' + (++count) + '*/';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is a word boundary; you need the start of a line, which is `^` (when used with modifier `s`). Like this:

```
var oldval = "public static void Main()\n\
         {\n\
             int a=1+1;\n\
             int b=1+1;\n\
         }";
var i = 0;
alert(oldval.replace(/^/mg, function(match) {
    return "/*" + (++i) + "*/"; }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

regex: `^(\s*.*)`

replace with: $Counter . $Matches[1]

Where $Counter is the variable containing your line numbers to be inserted.

Comment: wht's wrong with \b ? it should be a boundry for a word which is exactly what ^\b is.......no?

Comment: No, because \b is the boundary between a word and a not word. This boundary does not exist between the start of the sentence `^` and the first white space.